# Primarykey column auto-populated in SQL Server using Constraint and newid() function. How to achieve the same in Oracle

Tags: oracle

In Microsoft SQL Server we crate a table as below.

```
CREATE TABLE [dsb].[adjustment](
    [documentId] [int] NULL,
    [Events_id] [int] NULL,
    [REASON_CODE] [int] NULL,
    [impact_Category] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [sys_descr] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [descr] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [amount] [float] NULL,
    [Type] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [CREATED_T] [int] NULL,
    [tax_amount] [float] NULL,
    [tax_code] [varchar](255) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_adjustment] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dsb].[adjustment] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_adjustment_id]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [id]
```

As per this , whenever we insert a record into this `dsb.adjustment` table then a unique value is inserted into the `id` column and which is being used as a primary key as shown in the picture below. I believe that this technique is used in SQL Server for performance improvement (something related with `index`).

[image]

We want to create the same table with same structure in Oracle database. But I am not sure how to do something similar to `CONSTRAINT`in Oracle so that whenever we insert a record in Oracle we get a unique value in `id` column. What I know is that create table in Oracle and make `id` column as primary key and then do any one of these,

1. Create a trigger to insert a unique value into `id` but this seems
   expensive not sure though. OR
2. Insert `SYS_GUID()` into the `id` column while inserting a record into this table. OR
3. Use a `SEQUENCE` to insert sequence number into `id` column

But I am not sure which one is the best? Or any other way than the above three?

**EDIT** My question specify that which one is the best one in terms of performance. The already existing question does not have an answer for that.

Comment: As a side note, for SQL Server, a `CLUSTERED INDEX` on a column with a default value if `NEWID()` is a *very* bad idea; that's going to constantly be causing fragmentation issues.

Comment: Also, `float` for a column called `tax_amount` is a poor choice; monetary values and base-2 values *do not mix* well.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE table_name (ID NUMBER(10,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY)` [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1HJW4TG3)

Comment: @ThomA , May I know how it will lead to fragmentation issue in SQL Server.

Comment: Because the value of `NEWID()` isn't always ascending, @to-find , so the index is going to have to be *constantly* rewritten to add the new row into the relevant location. Depending on generated value, that might be 2% of the index, of 98%.

Comment: *"My question specify that which one is the best one in terms of performance"* What is "best" is entirely subjective without concrete requirements.

Comment: @ThomA , "2% of the index" means?

Comment: Exactly as it sounds, 2% of the index. Like 2% of 100 is 2. 2% of an index of that 2.